# selectedBackgroundView in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, uitableview

So I have a cell loaded directly from a nib file:

```
NSArray *cellContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ResultsTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [cellContents objectAtIndex:0];
```

In the nib file, there are a UITableViewCell and Two UIViews, each with its own subviews. Strucuture:

```
-TableViewCell
   Label 1
   Label 2
-UIView A
   UIView a
   UIView b
   UIImageView c
   UIImageView d
-UIView B
   UIView e
   UIView f
   UIImageView g
   UIImageView h
```

So the UIView A is connected to the backgroundView property for the UITableViewCell, the UIView B is connected to selectedBackgroundView property.

Problem:
So why A shows up fine as the background for the cell with all it's subviews, and the UIImageViews in B works fine, but the UIViews in B simply doesn't show up however I change it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I found my case. When I logged the RGB and alpha of the UIView's background color, I found that they were all getting set to 0 when the cell was selected:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGFloat red, green, blue, alpha;
    [viewE.backgroundColor getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];
    NSLog(@"Selected: Red=%f, Green=%f, Blue=%f, alpha=%f", red, green, blue, alpha);
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGFloat red, green, blue, alpha;
    [viewE.backgroundColor getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];
    NSLog(@"Deslected: Red=%f, Green=%f, Blue=%f, alpha=%f", red, green, blue, alpha);
}
```

Initially, nothing is selected. Tap a row in the table and the log shows:

```
Selected: Red=0.000000, Blue=0.000000, Green=0.000000, alpha=0.000000
```

and my subview does not appear (Note Alpha=0). Funny because when I logged viewE.alpha, it showed it was 1.

Tap the row again to deselect it:

```
Deselected: Red=0.667000, Blue=0.776000, Green=0.220000, alpha=1.000000
```

That's what I expect.

My table cell is a custom UITableViewCell. So in my custom UITableViewCell class I added this code:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    UIColor *saveColor = self.viewE.backgroundColor;
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    if (selected)
        self.viewE.backgroundColor = saveColor;
}
```

Now the subview viewE appears when the cell is selected.

It seems like the code here is compensating for a condition that should not have existed in the first place, but it works!